# How do I get my columns to line up?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to JS. I am trying to get the headers on my table to line up with the table data. Normally easy to do, however, in my case I am appending the td with JQuery. I have tried everything I can think of. I am using Bootstrap. Using the class col-md-x doesn't work. Using width="X" doesn't work. I can get the td to spread across the page, but them the header don't line up.

Here is the image of the problem: 
[image: columns don't line up]

Here is the HTML NB Not relevant to the question, however, the "form::select" is in Laravel:

```
 <h4>Add A Product</h4>
{!! Form::select('categories[]',$categories,null, ['class'=>'form-control categories', 'placeholder'=>'None']) !!}

<div class="hide_table show_table table-responsive ">

<table class=".table" >
<thead>

    <tr>
    <th class="col-md-2">Product</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Price</th>
    <th class="col-md-2">Add to Quote</th>
    </tr>

</thead>
    <tbody class = "row cat_products form-control">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'category_prices/' + value,
        success: function (categories) {
             $cat_products.empty();

            $.each(categories, function (i, product) {$(".cat_products").append('<tr><td>' +product.product_name+ '</td><td>' +product.price+ '</td><td> <input type="checkbox" value="cat_id"></td></tr>').css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(10, 30, 41, 0.05)",
                    "border": "solid 1.5px lightblue",
                    "border-radius": "5px",
                    "height":"auto",
                    // "width":"800px",
                });

                $("td").addClass("col-md-2");
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: remove "form-control" class from the tbody. It's typically used for intractable fields such as dropdown, textboxes. Also, assign width to both th,td. Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19244/

Comment: Many Thanks ! You are a mega Star !!

Comment: No worries. Glad it worked out for you :)